# Deployed Managed VMs version has a size of 0 bytes

Tags: google-managed-vm

Yesterday, I updated my gcloud components (via gcloud components update), and today I deployed a new Managed VMs version which is taking up 0 Bytes, according to the Versions page on the console.  Does anyone know if this is a known issue introduced by the latest gcloud sdk update?

Comment: same here, 0 byte for my vm :-(