# Managed VM instance is created empty

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, managed-vm

When I run

```
gcloud preview app deploy /yamls/app.yaml
```

it executes with no error messages or warnings, and I see a new managed VM instance in a developer console. The problem is that this instance has a size of 0 bytes, and, obviously, does not work.

It looks like I am not the first one to [run into this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650863/deployed-managed-vms-version-has-a-size-of-0-bytes), but there was no response to that question. Hopefully, this time someone knows how to answer it.

Here is the contents of app.yam, if it matters:

```
runtime: java7
vm: True
module: 'backend'
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 20
  cool_down_period_sec: 60
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.75
inbound_services:
- warmup
threadsafe: True
auto_id_policy: default
health_check:
  enable_health_check: True
resources:
  cpu: 0.5
  memory_gb: 1.3
  disk_size_gb: 10.0
api_version: '1.0'
handlers:
- url: /
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /_ah/.*
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /z
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: .*\.jsp
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /.*/
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
- url: /z/.*
  script: unused
  login: optional
  secure: optional
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide a minimal reproduction of this? How consistent is this behavior?

Comment: It happens every time I am trying to deploy. Backend is my App Engine module, which has a single servlet in it.

Answer (score 0):

From [Configuring the VM Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/config):

> There are two kinds of configuration files. Which one you use depends
>   on the language you are using and whether you are using standard or
>   custom runtimes:
>
> Use `appengine-web.xml` for:
>
> - Modules running the Java standard runtime
> - Modules using a custom
>     runtime based on the Java standard runtime
>     (gcr.io/google_appengine/java-compat base)
>
> Use `app.yaml` for:
>
> - Modules running the Python and Go standard runtimes
> - Any module running
>     in a custom runtime that is not based on the Java standard runtime

Since you're Java runtime, you need to be using appengine-web.xml, not app.yaml.

From [Testing and deploying managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/#testing_and_deploying_managed_vms):

> These sample Java projects are available:
>
> [Java Hello World Quickstart](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-hello)

The instructions on the Hello World Quickstart github project use maven to deploy. From the [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-hello/blob/master/README.md):

```
mvn gcloud:deploy
```

Comment: From the documentation: If you use the gcloud app deploy command, remember that before you can run or deploy a Java app, you must compile the source code, and use your preferred Java tooling to generate a WAR directory. You must also migrate the contents of your WAR directory to `a set of yaml files` using the stage action of the appcfg command.

Comment: The documentation here looks out of date; please try using the Maven gcloud plugin or a similar supported solution.

Comment: Documentation page says that it was updated December 22, 2015 - only a few days before my question.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a support ticket with Google, and the issue has been resolved in the new version of gcloud.